# apt-get install returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: debian, docker

I'm trying to get forked-daapd to compile in a docker container based on hassio-addons/addon-debian-base which is debian buster slim with a few pre-configured packages.

All of my apt-get install are working fine (so the sources.list is valid and internet works and so on), except one : java.

```
20-06-01 20:19:29 ERROR (SyncWorker_19) [supervisor.docker.addon] Can't build local/armv7-addon-forked-daapd:dev: The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-11-jre-headless' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I've tried all the different variants (default-jre, default-jdk, without and without headless ..) and I always get a code 100.
I'm not getting the output of the build just the return code, and since according to the man page 100 is returned for any error I don't know what's failing.

Any idea of what could be going wrong trying to install openjdk on a debian buster slim on armv7 (armhf) ?

```
ARG BUILD_FROM=hassioaddons/debian-base:3.0.0
# hadolint ignore=DL3006
FROM ${BUILD_FROM}

# Set shell
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gpg gpg-agent dirmngr apt-transport-https
RUN curl -L https://apt.mopidy.com/mopidy.list -o /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mopidy.list
RUN curl -L https://apt.mopidy.com/mopidy.gpg -o /tmp/mopidy.gpg
RUN apt-key add /tmp/mopidy.gpg
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libcurl4-gnutls-dev
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-11-jre-headless
RUN ...
```

java is needed for antlr3.
Thanks